# jQuery load & load again function

Tags: jquery, html

I am using the jQuery load function to load a url into a div. Once that has successfully loaded, i want to load another url directly underneath the previous loaded content.

My html

```
<div id=content></div>
```

My jquery

```
$('#content').load('first_content.php', null, function() {
    $('#content').append().load('second_content.php');
});
```

The issue is that the second loaded content, completely replaces the first loaded content.

How can i append content after the first_content is loaded, so that it appears underneath?

thanks

Comment: if you replaced your second `.load()` with a `$('#content').load()` inside the parentheses of `.append()`, does that still wipe the original content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you're replacing #content content , try appending a new div with second content loaded.

```
$('#content').load('first_content.php', null, function() {
    $('#content').append($('<div/>').load('second_content.php'));
});
```

Comment: Did you try this?  I think the problem is that `.append()` doesn't return the new content (it returns the original jquery object) so this will just load the second content right over the first.

Comment: You can append a jQuery object instance created by $('<element/>').
Take a look at docs http://api.jquery.com/append/

**contentOne** or more additional DOM elements, arrays of elements, HTML strings, **or jQuery objects** to insert at the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 0):

Load the first block.  When that completes, create a div and load the second block into that.  When that one completes append the div into the content area.

```
$('#content').load('first_content.php', null, function() {
    $("<div>").load('second_content.php', function() {
        $(this).appendTo("#content");
    });
});
```